# Are there some free fonts for the small seal, large seal, and even oracle bone script styles?

Tags: resources, history, fonts

I'm very interested in the old forms of Chinese characters that you still see in many contexts including historical, artistic, and design contexts.

So I'm wondering if there are free fonts for these old script styles:

- **[Large Seal script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Seal_Script)** or **Great Seal script** (大篆, Dàzhuàn) - from before the Qin dynasty
  [image: large seal] is the large seal script style for `龍`
- **[Small Seal Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Seal_Script)** (小篆, xiǎozhuàn), also known as **Seal Script**, **Lesser Seal Script** and **Qin Script** (秦篆, Qínzhuàn), from the Qin dynasty
  [image: small seal] is the small seal script style for `龍`
- **[Oracle bone script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)** (甲骨文, jiǎgǔwén) - the earliest version of Chinese script. I'm expecting this is less plausible since there were surely far fewer characters back then.
  [image: bronze] is the oracle bone script style for `龍`

I really only want free fonts that I can use in web pages or in open source projects, or even edit. Modern font formats such as `OTF` / `TTF` that are supported on all modern operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some chinese [font](http://www.ibiblio.org/chinesehistory/contents/08fea/c02.html#Fonts) including small seal scripts, but I haven't tried it myself. Might be useful for u.